# Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

I am trying to do is read the content xml tag from the Youtube video URL using simplexml, but when I add the attributes function, it gives me the error:

Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Php code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FS5uQpBp8XI/related?v=2");

$content = $xml->children("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")->group->content[0]->attributes();

$src = $content->url;

echo $src;
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, would you mind including a sample XML from that URL?

Comment: <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/4LMR6W5Q82k?version=3&amp;f=related&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='1727' yt:format='5'/>

Comment: Amended my reply, but you may want to tell us, just WHAT exactly you're looking for in that huge XML. A single child? Or something deep down?

Comment: i want to get the URL attribute of every media:content nodes

Comment: The related links, located under 'entry'?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that is not belong to the simple xml object. Try to use the print_r so you can find which attribute are you suppose to print out